# How to add commission to products at catalog view in magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I wanted to add a certain percent of commission to all products in magento by using a custom module and for that I have used and event observer `<catalog_product_get_final_price>` but it shows the added price only at product view but not at catalog view. SO can anyone help me how to add it from catalog view onwards?

Thanks in advance....